# Init function for bootbox to use some code after showing dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor, bootbox

I want to display a textarea-element with bootbox. This textarea should be used with a WYSIWYG-editor, which will be initialized by

```
$('#editor').redactor();
```

So I want to add this in the moment the textarea is displayed. I tried this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Title",
    message: '<textarea id="editor"></textarea>',
    init: function () {
        $('#editor').redactor();
    }
});
```

But this seems to be wrong.

Comment: The issue is because `init()` is called *before* the UI of the dialog is in the DOM. This plugin seems *extremely* poor in the fact that it doesn't have any events you can hook to when content is displayed/hidden. For that reason I would suggest you use a different plugin completely.

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Have a search, there are literally hundreds of dialog libraries.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, bootbox is simply a wrapper around Bootstrap's modals, so it has those events: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events. Or, were you looking for events for when bootbox is generating it's own content for it's alert, confirm, and prompt helpers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a show event:

```
var box = bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Title",
    message: '<textarea id="editor"></textarea>'
});
box.bind('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $("#editor").redactor();
});
```